# TFS - Files doesn't get check out for edit automatically when I edit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vcs-checkout

I am using VS2010 SP1 and TFS Version 10.0.40219.417 
Now what happens is that I attempt to type in a non-checked out file, and well, nothing happens. VS does not check out the file. I have to manually check out the file for check in.

It's happening with me only. On my colleague system it's working fine. I have cross checked all the settings he has done in his VS2010. Please suggest what should I do ?

Answer (score 8):

You probably covered this in "I have cross checked all the settings", but I'm going to ask anyway.

From [How to: Disable Automatic Checkouts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x00bk11(v=vs.90).aspx)

> In Visual Studio, on the Tools menu, click Options.
>
> In the Options dialog box, click Source Control, and then click
>   Environment.
>
> In the On Edit box, select a different option than Check out
>   automatically. The other available options are as follows:
>
> - Prompt for check out
> - Prompt for exclusive checkouts
> - Do nothing
>
> Click OK.

Do you have "Do nothing" checked?

**EDIT:**

If the above setting is correct the next thing I would double check is if the solution is "Online". I have lost the connection without realizing it several times, it is worth an extra check.

To check:

> Right-click on the solution name at the top of the Solution
>   Explorer and check if you have the "Go Online" option

Comment: I have to Enable Automatic Checkouts, presently which is not working on my system.

Comment: The "Go Online" suggestion was priceless for me. Just what I was looking for, to see what I'd changed.